# Encoding Lists in Thrift (Python)

Tags: python, thrift, thrift-protocol, zipkin

I'm wondering what's the best way to binary encode a list of structs with ThriftPy. The only way I've found is to create another wrapper `struct` and remove the binary prefix/suffix from the stream but this is very hacky and there should definitely be a better way.

foobar.thrift:

```
struct Object {
  1: i32 num1 = 0,
  2: i32 num2,
}

struct ListContainer {
    1: list<Object> objects
}
```

app.py

```
foobar = thriftpy.load('foobar.thrift', module_name="foobar_thrift")

objects = [ ... list of Objects ... ]

thrift_obj = foobar.ListContainer(objects)

trans = TMemoryBuffer()
thrift_obj.write(TBinaryProtocol(trans))

encoded_list = bytes(trans.getvalue())[3:-1]
```

Comment: How would you define "best way" in the context of this question? And why do you remove the header at all? IOW, **what do you want to achieve**?

Comment: There's an existing API that expects an Array of Thrift objects and I want to use it. The API is implemented in Java which seems to support reading lists of objects (see [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/fe14098030ab7ee5e305376c232ac72d852890b5/zipkin/src/main/java/zipkin/internal/ThriftCodec.java#L409))

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... not particularly elegant but better than the previous one.

*foobar.thrift*:

```
struct Object {
  1: i32 num1 = 0,
  2: i32 num2,
}

typedef list<Object> ObjectList
```

*app.py*:

```
import thriftpy
from thriftpy.transport import TMemoryBuffer
from thriftpy.protocol.binary import write_val


foobar = thriftpy.load('foobar.thrift')


def write_list(trans, val, list_type):
    ttype, spec = list_type
    write_val(trans, ttype, val, spec=spec)

val = [foobar.Object(num1=8, num2=12)]

trans = TMemoryBuffer()
write_list(trans, val, foobar.ObjectList)
encoded_list = bytes(trans.getvalue())
```

I tried to see what the standard thrift implementation does. It doesn't make it any easier. It doesn't generate anything for the `ObjectList` so in order to achieve the same you have to do `thrift -gen py foobar.thrift` and then:

*app.py*:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('gen-py')

from foobar.ttypes import *
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.transport import TTransport


def write_list(trans, val):
    protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(trans)
    protocol.writeListBegin(TType.STRUCT, len(val))
    for values in val:
        values.write(protocol)
    protocol.writeListEnd()  # This is a nop

val = [Object(num1=8, num2=12)]

trans = TTransport.TMemoryBuffer()
write_list(trans, val)
encoded_list = trans.getvalue()
```

Comment: I was about to propose to just write the contents of the list (but not the list itself) one by one. But that's only a wild guess, never used Zipkin myself. Isn't there any doc or tutorial available that covers your use case?

Comment: There's something little [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/pyramid_zipkin-example/blob/master/transport.py) but as you can see, it also has hackery.

Comment: I guess the main question is, does Thrift allow encoding standalone lists of structs (not within another structs) or not? If yes, then those Python libraries should provide a way. If not (which seems likely) then Zipkin is using non-standard features.